# Youtube does not show ads on WKWebView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using WebKit Swift to load Youtube video on my app, i have used the following swift code and it plays YouTube videos successfully:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/") else { return }
        
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

However, the videos that play never contain any of the YouTube ads that I have selected to play at the start of the video. Anyone know how to fix this so adverts still play?

I would like Youtube show ads with WKWebView.

Comment: My guess would be that this is on purpose. They have strict contracts with their advertisers and the advertisers pay to be on YouTube not your app. They have to make sure that the platform showing the ad aligns with the advertisers brand.

Comment: thank you for your anwser, it just happens on iOS. Android side still show Youtube ads on webview, that's why it make the difference between Android and iOS